# Separator view with/without headers as per Android Material Design Guideline

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a separator with header per Google Material Design spec, and I couldn't get it to work. Why would google roll out a spec that is not even available on either support or target platform level? So here I am recreating material spec to work with the older version and here is what I got so far:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_task_header1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/drawable_separator"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#bfbfbf"
        android:text="Location"/>
```

I want to create a header, a separator of some sort. I don't want to use list because list will require me to create an adapter which I find really impractical in my case. I have to layout the UI using XML and I can't figure it out.

I need something to look like this, I need to have a header without the line separator and a header with one separator:

[image]

Also, I was able to achieve to create a header via TextView and set margin top and bottom. The problem is I can't show the drawable line on my case and I don't feel like I am doing the right thing here. Its too messy.

I appreciate if you don't post an answer indicating the use of a hackish solution. I don't like to go down that path for some reason. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

To add vertical separator, switch the `layout_width` and `layout_height` values

Comment: Gah, I think I am really just tired, maybe I forgot to set which width and height was set to 1dp, in my case I think it was width which was set to 1dp that is why it is not showing up. As I got home I will check it out, and will let you know. By far, this is the correct answer. Thank you!!!